# large amount of data TRIMMed on SSD

Tags: ssd, fstab, trim

I just recently set up a new PC with an SSD/HDD combo; my Linux partition on my SSD is mounted as `/` with `/home` mounted on my HDD.

I have the `noatime` and `discard` flags set for my SSD in `/etc/fstab`, but just to see what would happen I ran fstrim from the terminal when I rebooted a few times.
When I do it, the return is:

```
~> sudo fstrim -v /
/: 54.9 GiB (58889682944 bytes) trimmed
```

for reference, 54.9GiB is also the amount of free space on my 60GiB partition.

Is my entire partition being rewritten between each boot, and should I be concerned for my SSD? Is this just a result of having the discard flag enabled AND using the `fstrim` command? Should I only use one TRIM method and not the other?